# Word can't "print" an MDI file under limited user account (but it works as an admin)

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office

This is the fourth in an increasingly narrow and increasingly annoying series of questions related to a hard deadline today.

Anyone know internals of how Word "prints" MDI files?  My limited users have R/W access to the directory they're to be saved in, but the files are not getting saved.  This process does work under an administrator account - the file is successfully saved and preview is launched.

Suggestions for debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a sorry print driver wants to put its temporary files in an admin only location?  I had a pdf print driver that did that and I changed the rights to the dir and all was good.  You could use FileMon or other utilities from SysInternals (now Microsoft) to find this.